# How to get rid of an empty bar above TabBarController (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

[image]

There is an empty bar above the tap bar, and I don't know how to get rid of it. Even if I try to scroll long the view, the empty bar covers up the collection view. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by empty bar?

Comment: Do you see the empty bar above the UITabBar?

Comment: are you talking about the navigationbar? or the blank area above the tabs?

Comment: Yeah, that one. The collection view is constrained all the way to the bottom.

Comment: it seems that you pushed into tabVC twice debug

Comment: Um, I only see there is one segue from the Tab Bar Controller. How do you fix it?

Comment: debug, see if your are doing something programmatically too. can you show a screen shot of storyboard?

Comment: check Under Bottom Bars and Under Opaque Bars in the Storyboard.

Comment: ThanK YOU So MUCH! It works now :)

Comment: I just wanted to say that i think your design is beautiful on this application